# jquery tablesorter not working on input/select fields (IE8), works fine on all other text fields in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Also sorts all fields properly on all other browsers.

Only problem is IE8 when the field is an input field (jquery datepicker) or select box to be specific.

```
 <tr class="proj_rec" data-id="<?php echo $project->get_id(); ?>">
                    <td class="proj_id">
                        <?php echo $project->get_id(); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $project->get_desc(); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <select class="touch">
                            <?php echo $opt_html_business_area; ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_business_area(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <select class="touch">
                            <?php echo $opt_html_status; ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_status(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <select class="touch">
                            <?php echo $opt_html_type; ?>
                        </select>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_type(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_owner(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $project->get_enter_date(); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_est_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_due_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="edit">
                        <input type="text" class="touch dtpick">
                        </input>
                        <span class="look">
                            <?php echo $project->get_next_date(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </td>


//project events that happen only on page load
function on_load_events() {
    // Adding a new slot
    $('#add_project').click(function() {
        var emp = $('#entered_new').val();
        add_project(emp);
    });

    $('#project_table').bind('sortStart',function() {
        back_to_look();
        $('span.cmnt_active').each(function() {
            remove_comments($(this));
        });
    });

    $('#project_table').tablesorter({
        textExtraction: myTextExtraction
    });

    //todo: try getting the dataTable to work...
    //  it might be way better, just not sure how it would handle
    //  adding unrelated rows on the fly (comments)
    //$('#project_table').dataTable();
}

String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');};

var myTextExtraction = function(node)  
{
    var elem = $(node);
    var theVal = null;

    if (elem.hasClass('edit')) {
        elem.children().each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                theVal = $(this).val();
            }
        });

    } else {
        theVal = elem.text();
    }

    //console.log(theVal);


    var c = node.childNodes.length;

    if (c == 1) {
        theVal = node.innerHTML.trim();
    } else if (c == 5) {
        theVal = node.childNodes[3].innerHTML.trim();
    }

    //console.log(theVal);
    return theVal;

}
```

Do I need to have conditional statements like in this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/AqXEA/1/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the jsfiddle you posted did not have any datepicker inputs or selects in it.
I have created a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqXEA/16/), that hopefully represents your data. In your case you want your textExtraction function to be aware of the content and retrieve the proper values.The function below will get the value of inputs for the datepickers and the selected value for selects.

```
        textExtraction: function(node)  
        {
            var elem = $(node);
            var text = '';
            if(elem.find('input').length > 0){
                text = elem.find('input').val().trim();     
            } else if(elem.find('select').length > 0){
                text = elem.find('select option[selected]').text().trim();
            } else {
                text = elem.text().trim();
            }
          return text;
        }
```

Note this isn't the most efficient implementation depending on how much data you have but it should help get you going in the right direction. Hope that helps